# ManyToMany Relationship with additional fields Django Forms

Tags: python, django

For my Django project I am trying to create a singular form that allows me to add a row in my Pipeline model and link that row to the Process model through the PipelineProcess model. This is fairly straightforward by using ModelForms IF the PipelineProcess model did not have an extra field (phase).

models.py

```
class Pipeline(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    process = models.ManyToManyField(Process, through='PipelineProcess')

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'pipeline'


class Process(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'process'


class PipelineProcess(models.Model):
    pipeline = models.ForeignKey(Pipeline, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=False)
    process = models.ForeignKey(Process, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=False)
    phase = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'pipeline_process'
```

forms.py

```
class PipelineForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pipeline
        fields = ['name', 'sector', 'phase']
```

This form generates the following error which makes sense:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (phase) specified for Pipeline
```

I have tried looking up examples of other people but none of which are useful to me. Most were far too complicated for me to put into my own project. I am fairly new with Django and web dev in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error occurs because you've included `phase` within your `Meta.fields`, but the `Pipeline` doesn't have a `phase`. Did you mean `['name', 'sector', 'process']`?

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Your solution allows me to add the necessary rows in the PipelineProcess model but I am unable to populate the field PipelineProcess.phase. Do you know how to fix that? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I am afraid I don't know how to achieve that. If your research didn't return any solution, it might be worth a try to ask another question specifically about how to add a field of a `through` model to a form.

Answer (score 0):

try to make following adjustment:

**forms.py**

```
class PipelineForm(ModelForm):
    phase = forms.Charfield()

    class Meta:
        model = Pipeline
        fields = ['name', 'sector']
```

I didn't have to include "phase" in the `fields` list, for it to work